# Can only pull 2020 team roster using commonteamroster endpoint

Tags: python, pandas, nba-api

I'm currently attempting to grab the latest team rosters from the NBA using the commonteamroster endpoint, but it seems like whatever season_id I enter, it only returns the 2020 rosters.

The roster I am looking at grabbing can be found here:
https://www.nba.com/stats/team/1610612738/?Season=2021-22

My code

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import time

headers  = {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'x-nba-stats-token': 'true',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36',
        'x-nba-stats-origin': 'stats',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
        'Referer': 'https://stats.nba.com/',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    }

from nba_api.stats.endpoints import commonteamroster


# get teams from the reg season 2021-22
teamfinder = commonteamroster.CommonTeamRoster(season='2021-22',
                                              team_id='1610612738',
                                              league_id_nullable='00')
teams = teamfinder.get_data_frames()[0]

team_id = teams['TeamID'].unique().tolist()
team_ids = teams['TeamID'].unique().tolist()

teams_roster=[]

for team_id in team_ids:
    player_stats_data = commonteamroster.CommonTeamRoster(team_id=team_id, headers=headers, timeout=100)
    time.sleep(.600)
    df = player_stats_data.common_team_roster.get_data_frame()
    df['TeamID'] = team_id
    print(team_id)
    teams_roster.append(df)
```

This returns:

```
[        TeamID SEASON LeagueID               PLAYER NICKNAME  
 0   1610612738   2020       00         Jayson Tatum   Jayson   
 1   1610612738   2020       00       Carsen Edwards   Carsen   
 2   1610612738   2020       00         Jaylen Brown   Jaylen   
 3   1610612738   2020       00          Moses Brown    Moses   
 4   1610612738   2020       00     Payton Pritchard   Payton   
 5   1610612738   2020       00       Grant Williams    Grant   
 6   1610612738   2020       00     Tristan Thompson  Tristan   
 7   1610612738   2020       00        Jabari Parker   Jabari   
 8   1610612738   2020       00        Aaron Nesmith    Aaron   
 9   1610612738   2020       00         Marcus Smart   Marcus   
 10  1610612738   2020       00         Semi Ojeleye     Semi   
 11  1610612738   2020       00          Luke Kornet     Luke   
 12  1610612738   2020       00           Al Horford       Al   
 13  1610612738   2020       00  Robert Williams III   Robert   
 14  1610612738   2020       00       Romeo Langford    Romeo   
 15  1610612738   2020       00       Tremont Waters  Tremont   
 16  1610612738   2020       00        Evan Fournier     Evan   
 17  1610612738   2020       00           Tacko Fall    Tacko
```

It doesn't matter what I set my season number, it only pulls 2020 season roster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine. Did you not look at the output from:

```
# get teams from the reg season 2021-22
teamfinder = commonteamroster.CommonTeamRoster(season='2021-22',
                                              team_id='1610612738',
                                              league_id_nullable='00')
```

By default it grabs 2020 season. You neglected to add that season parameter in your for loop.

```
for team_id in team_ids:
    player_stats_data = commonteamroster.CommonTeamRoster(season='2021-22', team_id=team_id, headers=headers, timeout=100)   # <--- ADD YOUR season parameter!
    time.sleep(.600)
    df = player_stats_data.common_team_roster.get_data_frame()
    df['TeamID'] = team_id
    print(team_id)
    teams_roster.append(df)
```